# How to conditionally disable responsive nature in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have two separate theme desktop as well as mobile. In desktop theme, i used `Bootstrap` classes. And I knew that `Bootstrap` classes create the responsive layout. But I don't want the responsive layout in desktop theme.

please someone help me, How to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>size resolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    hello1
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    hello2
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    hello3
</div>
<section>
The online encyclopedia project Wikipedia is by far the most popular wiki-based website, and is one of the most widely viewed sites of any kind in the world, having been ranked in the top ten since 2007.[3] Wikipedia is not a single wiki but rather a collection of hundreds of wikis, one for each language. There are at least tens of thousands of other wikis in use, both public and private, including wikis functioning as knowledge management resources, notetaking tools, community websites, and intranets. The English-language Wikipedia has the largest collection of articles; as of September 2016, it had over five million articles. Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work".[4] "Wiki" (pronounced [ˈwiki][note 1]) is a Hawaiian word meaning "quick".
</section>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and disable responsive layout . web page content to be fixed layout even content width not to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-xs-` instead of `col-lg-` prefix to have columns work on all resolutions ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>size resolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    hello1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    hello2
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    hello3
</div>
<section>
The online encyclopedia project Wikipedia is by far the most popular wiki-based website, and is one of the most widely viewed sites of any kind in the world, having been ranked in the top ten since 2007.[3] Wikipedia is not a single wiki but rather a collection of hundreds of wikis, one for each language. There are at least tens of thousands of other wikis in use, both public and private, including wikis functioning as knowledge management resources, notetaking tools, community websites and intranets. The English-language Wikipedia has the largest collection of articles; as of September 2016, it had over five million articles. Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work".[4] "Wiki" (pronounced [ˈwiki][note 1]) is a Hawaiian word meaning "quick".
</section>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful :) Please mark the answer as accepted... maybe even upvote if you find it nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom `col-4` for yourself where you can define that it should be 33% wide. That's about what bootstrap is going to do except that they have that rule for different type of screen sizes. That makes it responsive.

If you don't want it responsive, take away that "cleverness" from it and just tell it to be the width you want it to.

You could add a css:

```
.col-4-custom {
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>size resolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style> 
        .col-4-custom {
            width: 33%;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
<div class="col-4-custom">
    hello1
</div>
<div class="col-4-custom">
    hello2
</div>
<div class="col-4-custom">
    hello3
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
<section>
The online encyclopedia project Wikipedia is by far the most popular wiki-based website, and is one of the most widely viewed sites of any kind in the world, having been ranked in the top ten since 2007.[3] Wikipedia is not a single wiki but rather a collection of hundreds of wikis, one for each language. There are at least tens of thousands of other wikis in use, both public and private, including wikis functioning as knowledge management resources, notetaking tools, community websites and intranets. The English-language Wikipedia has the largest collection of articles; as of September 2016, it had over five million articles. Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work".[4] "Wiki" (pronounced [ˈwiki][note 1]) is a Hawaiian word meaning "quick".
</section>

   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like this if you are not familiar in manually outlining `Twitter Bootstrap` applications. I found this tool greatly helpful for document outlining `Twitter Bootstrap` application responsive layouts during the initial phase.

http://shoelace.io/